# Hyper V Server not findable by name

Tags: dns, hyper-v

I am setting up a Hyper V 2008 R2 Server on my home network to evaluate it for general virtualization usage at work (software development test lab etc).

I don't have a domain at home so its just a workgrouped network. I've got the server installed and running but the problem is the server name won't resolve. NetBios over tcp/ip is enabled and I can remote desktop to it by IP address.

The Hyper V server is just stripped down Windows Server 2008 so it only has a command line and not much else for management UI. Plus not being much of a networking guy I am mostly fumbling around in the dark.

How can I configure it to register itself such that its name will resolve?

Thanks,
Don

Comment: For server type questions you might want to ask over at http://serverfault.com/ instead of Super User.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hyper-V does not need to be connected to a domain, however to configure network setting in R2 is fairly straigh forward.

> - Log on to Hyper-V
> - At Powershell menu select 8
> - Select the Network Adapter by Index number
> - Configure Settings

As for resolving the name, Windows Server 2008 Core disables everything via the firewall, so I would suggest that you disable the firewall first to ensure that this is not what is causing the problem. You can disable the firewall using:

> netsh firewall set opmode disable

And to re-enable:

> netsh firewall set opmode enable

Lastly use option 4 to enable all the Remote Management features which means you can manage the complete machine remotely once you have fixed the name resolution, or alternatively using the IP address.

If you are using DHCP you can also try running:

> ipconfig /flushdns

And

> ipconfig /registerdns

Which may fix the connectivity problem as well, but if not in a domain I am not convinced it will work.

Comment: Thanks @Diago. flush and reigsterdns didn't solve it (I am using DHCP). Turning off the firewall did though so that is the culprit with the name resolution.